# Edits not effects on solution explorer after closing vs 2022 and reopen it. Even though it effects after i add it directly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, csproj, solution-explorer

I am using visual studio 2022 and .Net 6
in .csproj file i am adding this

```
`<ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="./Db/Db.cs" />
        <Compile Include="./Db/Constructors.cs">
            <DependentUpon>./Db/Db.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="./Db/Tables.Internal.cs">
            <DependentUpon>./Db/Db.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="./Db/Tables.DbDirect.cs">
            <DependentUpon>./Db/Db.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="./Db/Tables.InMemory.cs">
            <DependentUpon>./Db/Db.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="./Db/Views.cs">
            <DependentUpon>./Db/Db.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="./Db/Views.Filter.cs">
            <DependentUpon>./Db/Db.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
`
```

and it effect on solution explorer like this

[image]

But after closing the visual studio and reopen it the changes on .csproj file still exist but the solusion explorer not efected it become like this

[image]

i try yo clean solution and delete .vs directory and delete bin and proj folders but not work. it needs to delete the edits and add it again every time i reopn vs.
any help please i've been a while with this problem.

solution for this problem